# Can you use a multiclass classifier of a feature(s) when processing/feature engineering on top of a (stacked) classifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, feature-engineering

Can you use a multiclass classifier of a feature(s) when processing/feature engineering on top of a stacked classifier?

Use-case: 
You have 10 features to use in a multi-class classification problem. 1 of those features is text, the others and categorical, numerical, and time.

9 features get put through typical pipeline steps:

Similar to the sklearn Column Transformer with mixed types example:

```
numeric_features = ['age', 'fare']
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler())])

categorical_features = ['embarked', 'sex', 'pclass']
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='missing')),
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])
```

The text feature is "preprocessed" or engineered by passing it through a text pipeline that contains a domain-specific trained vector model. The output of which is a 100-dimensional vector/array passed into a multi-class classifier that outputs the classification probabilities ("predict_proba").

These probabilities would then be combined with the features from the above preprocessor before being passed into a classifer/stacking classifier:

```
text_features = ['domain text']
text_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('text_vectors', (TextVectorizer() ),
    ('predict_prob',  DecisionTreeClassifier(params='awesome'))])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('text', text_transformer, text_features),
        ('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_features),
        ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_features)])


clf = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                      ('classifier', LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs'))])
```

In several different ways, I have used sklearn mixins (BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin, ClassifierMixin) to create custom class or classes to do this but I have failed miserably. Lots of errors. Seems like I can't get a classifier to work inside of a transformer class.

Here is an example of one of my many attempts

```
class TextVectorClassifierProba(ClassifierMixin,BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    """ """

    def __init__(self):


        pass

    def transform(self, df, y=None):
        """The workhorse of this feature extractor"""
        vector = Pipeline(steps=[('word_vectorizer', TextVectorTransformer())
                         ,('classifier',DecisionTreeClassifier())])


        return vector.fit(df).predict_proba(df)

    def fit(self, df, y=None):
        """Returns `self` unless something different happens in train and test"""
        return self
```

The real question is: 
Can you fit then predict as part of a transformation on a subset your data in a stacked ensemble?

In several different ways, I have used sklearn mixins (BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin, ClassifierMixin) to create custom classes to do this but I have failed miserably.

Will this actually work? Has anyone ever seen anything like this or am I just dreaming up crazy things?

Any insight or thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks!